# View A Pandas Cell If A Different Cell Is X

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to view the value of the cell in column A that is in the same row as the highest value in column B. How can I do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);df

Out[56]:
            A           B           C           D
0    1.884824    1.733768   -1.563408    0.102643
1   -0.863316    0.188670    1.869908    2.195077
```

That is, I want return 1.884824 from column A because 1.733768 is the largest value in column B.

Answer (score 1):

Use loc and idxmax:

```
df.loc[df['B'].idxmax(),'A']
```

Example:

```
In [56]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df

Out[56]:

          A        B         C         D
0  0.757759 -0.98418 -0.931652  0.858322
1 -0.886566  0.40201  0.969339  0.042881

[2 rows x 4 columns]

In [57]:
df.loc[df['B'].idxmax(),'A']

Out[57]:

-0.88656646696612762
```

Comment: I think you should use `ix` (or plain `[]`) instead of `iloc`, since `idxmax` will return the actual index, so `iloc` will fail if the indexes aren't consecutive integers starting from 0.

Comment: @BrenBarn so `df.ix[df['B'].idxmax()]['A']` is better? I've updated my answer, I thought in this case there would be no difference between `iloc` and `ix`, I wasn't aware of the index limitation

Comment: ``ix`` would give the wrong answer IF it had an non-natural integer index (e.g. 2,4,6,8). You should actually use ``.loc`` (and dont't chain index!), e.g. do ``df.loc[df['B'].idxmax(),'A']``

Comment: @jeff: Is there any official guideline these days on when you should use `loc` vs `ix`?

Comment: well, use ``ix`` when you simultaneously need both location and position indexing on different axes, e.g. ``df.ix['A',-1]``, otherwise I always use ``.loc``